# Convert Timestamp in Millesecond Epoch Flutter

Tags: flutter, timestamp, milliseconds

Hello I have a data from Firestore which is the Timestamp and it is displayed so:

```
July 21, 2021 at 1:03:56 AM UTC + 2
```

and I want to convert this data into Millisecond Epoch for example....:

```
1626876187000
```

How I can convert it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it like below

```
DateTime date =DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());
final dateInEpoch =date.milliSecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a `DateTime` as shown [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html). From there you can access the `.milliSecondsSinceEpoch` or `microsecondsSinceEpoch` properties.

```
DateTime converted = DateTime.parse("July 21, 2021 at 1:03:56 AM UTC + 2")
print("${converted.milliSecondsSinceEpoch}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a Timestamp to epoch time, use the `toMillis()` method on the Timestamp in firestore.